# solidity array mapping with array inside struct

Tags: solidity, remix

Unable to execture createSchema function. It gives following error

revert
The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Testing {

    struct Schema {
        mapping(string => string) entity;
    }

    struct SchemaMapping {
        // mapping(string => string) key;
        // mapping(string => string) value;
        string[] key;
        string[] value;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => Schema) schemas;
    mapping(uint256 => SchemaMapping[]) schemaMappings;

    function createSchema(uint256 id, string memory key, string memory value) public {
        SchemaMapping[] storage schemamapping = schemaMappings[id];

        schemamapping[id].key.push(key);
        schemamapping[id].value.push(value);

        schemas[id].entity[key] = value;
    }

    function getSchemaElemet(uint256 id) public view returns (SchemaMapping[] memory) {
        return schemaMappings[id];
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the expected structure of `schemaMappings`? Is your intention to have 1) multiple `SchemaMapping`s (and each of them multiple `key`s and `value`s) for each ID? Or 2) just one `SchemaMapping` for each ID (while still keeping multiple `key`s and `value`s for each `SchemaMapping`)

Comment: Since my schemas hold multiple key,value in the entity mapping, for example 
schemas[0].entity["location"] = "Bangladesh"; schemas[0].entity["price"] = "20"; Now i want to get all the key,value by looping over the schemaMapping or want to have a function that will return all that key pair for specifc index. @PetrHejda

Answer (score 1):

I adjusted your smart contract. The issue in your original contract is that you were trying to add values into schemaMapping without create SchemaMapping at specific index.

Smart contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Testing {

    struct Schema {
        mapping(string => string) entity;
    }

    struct SchemaMapping {
        string[] key;
        string[] value;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => Schema) schemas;
    mapping(uint256 => SchemaMapping[]) schemaMappings;

    function createSchema(uint256 id, string memory key, string memory value) public {
        SchemaMapping[] storage schemamapping = schemaMappings[id];
        // NOTE: I created an empty space in storage for create object and after bind it with values.
        SchemaMapping storage singleSchemaItem = schemamapping.push();
        // NOTE: I put values inside keys
        singleSchemaItem.key.push(key);
        singleSchemaItem.value.push(value);

        schemas[id].entity[key] = value;
    }

    function getSchemaElemet(uint256 id) public view returns (SchemaMapping[] memory) {
        return schemaMappings[id];
    }
    
}
```

Comment: It's working fine so the point i missed is to create a space in storage for create object